# Iterable works with the spread syntax, but not with RxJs `from`

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I wrote the following iterable. It works with the spread syntax, but does not work with RxJs `from`.

```js
class Queue {

  items = [];
 
  enqueue(item) {
    return this.items.push(item);
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (const i of this.items) {
      yield i;
    }
  }

}

const q = new Queue();
q.enqueue('foo');

console.log(...q)
```

But the following does not print out the contents of `q` as expected:

```
from(q).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it - it seems to work](https://jsbin.com/xiqacewezo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ thank you, you are right, it works in jsbin but in my project I'm using Typescript target ES6 and RxJs "6.2.2" `from(queue).pipe(tap(x => console.log(x)))` is undefined

Comment: *This* is why we need a [mcve]. You said something doesn't work and showed code that *does* work. How can we guess what the error is, if any? Your comment contains *completely different code*. Is that what you're calling? Do you call `.subscribe()` on this?

Comment: Yes I do. I posted a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597556/symbol-property-not-transpiled-as-expected

Comment: [If you call `.subscribe()` it should work](https://jsbin.com/wikudir/1/edit?js,console). However, [it doesn't, if you don't call it](https://jsbin.com/xemuyuh/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help on the other q, that was mny mistake. Here, the problem appears to be that your solution works in jsbin (and [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rx-playground-1unfdh)), but it does not work in my app. A language versioning issue?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe it's something to do with the compilation or some code elsewhere. I used the same version as you mentioned 6.2.2. According to the documentation, that would be correct. I don't see a reason *here* why it wouldn't work. Since you say it doesn't, then logically there is an issue but elsewhere.

Comment: I found the problem! removing `length` getter fixed the issue. Still streange because I have the `length` on my JSbin example and works, not in my app!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Perhaps if it sees `length` it treats the object as an array-like, however, it doesn't have any indeces assigned.